# Problems in Quick Sort Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, quicksort

I am having a problem with my Quick Sort code. I am new to coding and python(python 3.6), any help would be really appreciated. I have seen several implementations of Quick Sort online but I want to figure out what is really wrong with my code. I am pasting my code below:

```
def Partition(A):
    q = A[0]
    i = 1
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        if A[j] < q:
            A[j], A[i] = A[i], A[j]
            i = i + 1
    A[0], A[i - 1] = A[i - 1], A[0]
    return i - 1

def QuickSort(A):
    if len(A) <= 1:
        return A
    else:
        q = Partition(A)
        QuickSort(A[ : q])
        QuickSort(A[q + 1 : ])
        return A

A = [7, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 8]
Sorted = []
Sorted = QuickSort(A)
print(Sorted)
```

For the input above I am getting the output [2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8] instead of getting a sorted list in ascending order.

Comment: Can you describe what is wrong or what output you expect and what you are getting? Dumping your code and asking what is wrong with it is off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: @StefanPochmann please help me with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These try to sort **copied** parts of `A`:

```
    QuickSort(A[ : q])
    QuickSort(A[q + 1 : ])
```

They return something, but you ignore what they return, so it's lost. You should write their results back into `A`:

```
    A[ : q] = QuickSort(A[ : q])
    A[q + 1 : ] = QuickSort(A[q + 1 : ])
```

After this change, your result is the expected `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Comment: Clearing up my comment trail. You were right to call me out on this and I've enjoyed our performance discussions in the past :) The problem with being catapulted into programming is that you have no idea of your blindspots... but I'm an engineer; everything I know about programming ultimately comes from this site in some way.

Comment: @roganjosh Heh... not sure SO is the best way to learn programming :-). I do come here to *practice* and to learn *more*, but for example when I recently got into Ruby, I worked through a Ruby beginner's book.